# Avoiding one domain to be indexed by search engines

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have a site that is available through 2 domains. One domain is one that I got for free with a hosting plan and don't want to promote. However when I perform search queries, pages from my site on that domain pop up.

What techniques are there to avoid the one domain from indexing while the other is perfectly indexed? Remember it's one hosting space with the exact same files on.

I have already submitted it in Google webmaster tools but that only works for Google obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up a sitewide 301 redirect from the domain you don't want to use too the other one. That way you will remove it from indexing as well as move people to use the correct one. You can probably do it in the .htaccess file (apache server). I'm not at my computer at the moment so can't easily give you the commands.

Comment: I'm on a Windows server so that would be web.config. The thing is I only have one hosting space so I can't set different configurations for the domains I believe...

Comment: I thing you can filter redirects by domain/host in the web.config routing elements